# 'dim': identifier not found

Tags: c++, identifier

I am getting this error message:

> error C3861: 'dim': identifier not found

Here are my includes:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "HSMBTPrintX.h"
#include "HSMBTPrintXCtrl.h"
#include "HSMBTPrintXPropPage.h"


#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

Here is my function:

```
#define MSS_PORTS_BASE _T("Software\\Microsoft\\Bluetooth\\Serial\\Ports")
bool FindBluetoothPort(TCHAR name[16]) {
    HKEY hKey, hRoot;
    TCHAR szPort[20] = _T(""), szPortString[20];
    DWORD len, dwIndex=0;
    bool bFound=false;
    INT i = 0, rc;
    DWORD dwNSize;
    DWORD dwCSize;
    TCHAR szClass[256];
    TCHAR szName[MAX_PATH];
    FILETIME ft;
    hRoot = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if (RegOpenKeyEx (hRoot, MSS_PORTS_BASE, 0, 0, &hKey) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        rc = GetLastError();
        return 0;
    }
    dwNSize = dim(szName);    <---- ~~ !! HERE IS THE LINE THAT ERRORS
    dwCSize = dim(szClass);     <---- HERE IS THE LINE THAT ERRORS  !! 
    rc = RegEnumKeyEx (hKey, i, szName, &dwNSize, NULL, szClass, &dwCSize, &ft);
    while (rc == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        // how many children
        TCHAR szCurrentKey[MAX_PATH];
        wcscpy(szCurrentKey, MSS_PORTS_BASE);
        wcscat(szCurrentKey, TEXT("\\"));
        wcscat(szCurrentKey, szName);
        wcscat(szCurrentKey, TEXT("\\"));
        len = sizeof(szPort);
        if(RegGetValue(hRoot, szCurrentKey, _T("Port"), NULL, (LPBYTE)szPort, &len)) {
            wsprintf(szPortString, _T("%s:"), szPort);
            bFound = true;
            break;
        }
        dwNSize = dim(szName);
        rc = RegEnumKeyEx(hKey, ++i, szName, &dwNSize, NULL, NULL, 0, &ft);
    }

    if(bFound)
        _tcscpy(name, szPortString);

    return bFound;
}
```

As you can see, the two lines that use this are:

```
dwNSize = dim(szName);

dwCSize = dim(szClass);
```

Why is that an error?

Comment: Which tutorial are you using to learn C++? C++ does not use the word `dim`.

Comment: This is code that i have obtained from somewhere else.  We (our company) was provided with this as a means of printing from a wireless scanner via bluetooth.. and told we needed to implement activeX. I'm the lucky one who gets to figure it out, and apparently try to fix certain parts too :)

Comment: Apparently someone at the other company needs to change their light bulb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are wanting `sizeof`:

```
dwNSize = sizeof(szName);
dwCSize = sizeof(szClass);
```

`sizeof` returns the number of bytes of the object/variable.  However, I just looked at the documentation for the API RegEnumKeyEx, and it needs the number of characters.  So I think it actually should divide by the size of a TCHAR (which will be 1 or 2 depending on if your are building for Unicode).

```
dwNSize = sizeof(szName) / sizeof(TCHAR);
dwCSize = sizeof(szClass) / sizeof(TCHAR);
```

Comment: that makes sense... had i just paid more attention to the variable name rather than letting myself get lost in my confusion.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You want `sizeof`.

If you originally learned `dim`, that was probably a macro that really calls `sizeof` behind the scenes.

Comment: that makes sense... had i just paid more attention to the variable name rather than letting myself get lost in my confusion.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have in the past used the following macro:

```
#define DIM(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof((x)[0]))
```

It is not provided by any of the standard includes, you have to define it for yourself.

You can also do a more modern version using a template function:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t dim(const T (& array)[N])
{
   return N;
}
```

Comment: seeing code snippets like this, makes me really want to learn C++.  Been doing VB.net for 3 years, did a little java here and there but nothing advanced.

Comment: @Adam, this is hardly exemplary code, I'm surprised by your comment. Macros are very primitive by today's standards.

Comment: @Adam I've added the template version which is a bit more interesting, at least to me.